# why $_GET value is different than URL

Tags: php, get

I have a url like this

```
http://example.com/folder/component/mycom/?insid=7&amp;test=685286640293e700bc9440cafb587290
```

I need to get value of `test`. When I echo `$_GET['test']` it returns `685286640293e700bc9440cafb587290?url=component/mycom/` . It is happening for last variable of url.I dont know why is this so? 
Thanks

Comment: you mean `token` rather than test?

Comment: Where is the .php file located on your system? The 'http://example.com/folder/component/mycom/?' makes me wonder if ../folder/ has some sort of weird Apache rewrite rule or something.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Test` isn't being sent in the `$_GET` that you displayed?

You have : `insid=7` and `token=685286640293e700bc9440cafb587290` with a malformed `&` between them that is the HTML code for & rather than the & itself.

Your URL at the moment is this:

```
http://example.com/folder/component/mycom/?insid=7&amp;test=685286640293e700bc9440cafb587290
```

If you change it to

```
http://example.com/folder/component/mycom/?insid=7&test=685286640293e700bc9440cafb587290
```

I would be willing to bet you will get your code working :)

Comment: Then it is the ampersand that needs to be corrected. Change the URL to contain the proper `&` symbol instead.

Comment: Thanks now its working some problem with joomla JRoute::_() function.I have removed it now.Thank you all..